# Using the value of an if parameter without saving it into a variable

Tags: python

Is it possible to *"re-use"* the value of a parameter of an `if`-clause?

I have a function that returns either `True` or a dictionary:

```
def foo():
    if random.randint(0, 1) == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return {"time": time.time()}
```

If `foo()` returns the dictionary, I also want to return it. If `foo()` returns `True` I want to just continue.

Currently I'm using:

```
if_value = foo()

if if_value is not True:
    return if_value
```

My goal would be to avoid saving the return value of the function into a variable, because it makes my code really ugly (I need to do this about 20 times in a row).

When using a Python shell, it seems to work like this:

```
if function_that_returns_True_or_an_int() is not True:
    return _
```

Any suggestions about this?

Comment: So you're trying to save the value of an expression without saving the value of the expression as a variable?

Comment: I don’t see a function statement

Comment: It's hard to really answer without some more context because the answer is going to really depend on your use-case. What happens if the condition is not true? There is a `return` there but no function. Please provide a [mre] so it is easy to understand the scenario. For example, you might be able to do something like `return func() or some_value`, but again - it is hard to say without a proper [mre]

Comment: Also, what Python version are you using because [the walrus operator](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions) might be exactly what you need (Python 3.8 onwards)

Comment: You only return False when the function returns False, so `if not function_that_returns_True_or_an_int(): return False`

Comment: @AlejandroBlasco The name of the function `function_that_returns_True_or_an_int` suggests that you are wrong (it will return the int)...

Comment: So you only return when the function returns a number. Try: `if type(function()) == int: print(function())`, although I don't like to evaluate twice a function

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the confusion: I will edit the question to add an example.. @Tomerikoo I am using 3.9, the walrus operator works perfectly!

Comment: Well, to be honest your edit didn't really fix what (to me) is the real problem. `foo` itself was less important, more important is what you do with it which is currently not clear. You do `return value` in case the value is not true, but what is the `else`? What is the function this `return` belongs to? Knowing this will allow to offer other solutions apart from using the walrus (maybe ones that remove the need of a condition altogether)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [walrus operator](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions) (`:=`) to declare a variable and assign to it, then do your comparison

```
if (x := your_function()) == condition:
    # something
else:
    # something else

print(x)  # x is still a named variable and in scope
```